# R: How can I apply column name changes to many data frames at once?

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, multiple-columns

I am trying to replace certain words in the column headers of over 100 data frames.I have a string that works perfectly:

```
names(singledataframe) <- gsub(x = names(singledataframe), pattern = "Int'l", 
replacement = "International")
```

I am trying to apply this to all the frames I've made. I used c()to refer to them under `AllFrames`. I was trying to make a function of the string that works on one frame and apply it to `AllFrames`, with a for loop.

```
ChangeName1 <- function(singledataframe) {
  gsub(x = names(singledataframe), pattern = "Int'l", replacement = "International") 
  }
```

then something like:

```
for (i in 1:length(names(AllFrames))) {lapply(i, ChangeName1)
}
```

I get no errors, but randomly checking individual frames shows the intended effect did not take.I've tried so many variations, but I'm stuck! I'm thinking maybe I need to edit the c() that refers to `AllFrames` in a better way.

- I apologize if any of this is unclear or I generally posted incorrectly. It's my first time and all this is new two me. Thanks in advance for any direction or help you can give.

Comment: `lapply(AllFrames,ChangeName1)`

Comment: @Onyambu Thank's for the edit. I'm somewhat new to this and can get too in my head, even with simple things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not assigning and returning the changed `data.frame` from your function. Try:

```
ChangeName1 <- function(singledataframe) {
    names(singledataframe) <- gsub(
        x = names(singledataframe), 
        pattern = "Int'l", 
        replacement = "International");
    return(singledataframe);
}
```

---

### Update

Let's assume your `data.frame`s are stored in a `list`; I will use some randomly generated data:

```
set.seed(2017);
lst <- list(
    data.frame(rnorm(10), rnorm(10)),
    data.frame(rnorm(10), rnorm(10)));
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) { colnames(x) <- c("A", "Int'l"); x });
#[[1]]
#              A      Int'l
#1   1.434201478  0.3427681
#2  -0.077291959  1.5724254
#3   0.739137231 -0.7467347
#4  -1.758604727  0.3066498
#5  -0.069825227 -1.4304858
#6   0.451905527  1.1944265
#7  -1.958366456 -0.4820681
#8  -0.001524259  1.3178624
#9  -0.265336001 -1.1298316
#10  1.563222619 -0.9263514
#
#[[2]]
#             A      Int'l
#1   0.14070941 -0.6831744
#2  -0.85223255  0.2410894
#3   1.90339718  0.5894319
#4  -1.64818594 -0.9306249
#5   0.75962477  0.2974619
#6   0.06229087  3.1372771
#7  -0.38903119 -1.0275347
#8   0.63666563  1.9418028
#9  -0.86778544 -0.2779562
#10  0.09873361 -0.2215888
```

Then we can simply `lapply` the function `changeName1` to all `list` elements:

```
lapply(lst, ChangeName1);
#[[1]]
#              A International
#1   1.434201478     0.3427681
#2  -0.077291959     1.5724254
#3   0.739137231    -0.7467347
#4  -1.758604727     0.3066498
#5  -0.069825227    -1.4304858
#6   0.451905527     1.1944265
#7  -1.958366456    -0.4820681
#8  -0.001524259     1.3178624
#9  -0.265336001    -1.1298316
#10  1.563222619    -0.9263514
#
#[[2]]
#             A International
#1   0.14070941    -0.6831744
#2  -0.85223255     0.2410894
#3   1.90339718     0.5894319
#4  -1.64818594    -0.9306249
#5   0.75962477     0.2974619
#6   0.06229087     3.1372771
#7  -0.38903119    -1.0275347
#8   0.63666563     1.9418028
#9  -0.86778544    -0.2779562
#10  0.09873361    -0.2215888
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. A quick follow up: Calling the individual frames still shows it did not work. However, names(AllFrames) shows that it did there. What am I doing wrong so that it will apply these changes to all frames covered by AllFrames?

Comment: @Kootseeahknee I updated my solution, please take a look. To best utilise `lapply` you should have all of your `data.frame`s in a `list`. Then simply `lapply` your function to all `list` elements.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help! Unfortunately it doesn't seem to want to take. I tried to apply your update, but I had to modify it since I have over 300 columns per dataset and I need any instance of Int'l to be International.
 
Thank you for trying, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Kootseeahknee What do you mean by *"it doesn't seem to want to take"*? Running the example in my solution works. You need your data to be in a `list` of `data.frame`s. Have you checked that this is the case? Then make sure to *assign* the output of `lapply` to an object, e.g. `lst <- lapply(lst, ChangeName1)`. `lst` will then consist of a `list` of `data.frame`s where column names have been replaced according to the rules defined in `ChangeName1`.

Comment: I apologize for my phrasing. Any issue I'm having is definitely on my end. I did make sure that `AllFiles` is a list of about 178 data.frames. 

`I used ChangeName1 <- function(singledataframe) {
  names(singledataframe) <- gsub(
    x = names(singledataframe), 
    pattern = "Int'l", 
    replacement = "International");
 
}` on one data.frame. Then I did what you specified as:

`AllFrames <- lapply(AllFrames, function(x) { colnames(x) <- ("Int'l"); x })`. I may have misunderstood what **A** was in your string and removed the `c()` part as I wasn't specifying column names.

Comment: @Kootseeahknee No, that's not what I did in my example; take another look. The last step should be `AllFrames <- lapply(AllFrames, ChangeName1)`.

Comment: Ah OK. That fixed it, it did make the change. I think my confusion was that I haven't unpackaged the list of `AllFiles` so that each data.frame within it also has the change. I was checking in the wrong place. Thank you , again!